# How to install Kinect drivers?

Tags: drivers, 15.04, kinect

I have a Kinect v2 and I am trying to connect it to my laptop using [libfreenect2](https://github.com/OpenKinect/libfreenect2).

Here is what I have done so far :

1. Got the `libfreenect2` project

   ```
   git clone https://github.com/OpenKinect/libfreenect2.git
   ```
2. Installed needed dependencies

   ```
   sudo apt-get install build-essential libturbojpeg libjpeg-turbo8-dev libtool autoconf libudev-dev cmake mesa-common-dev freeglut3-dev libxrandr-dev doxygen libxi-dev automake

   cd libfreenect2/depends
   sh install_ubuntu.sh
   sudo apt-get install libglfw3-dev
   ```
3. I have an Intel GPU, installed `beignet-dev` for OpenCL

   ```
   sudo apt-get install beignet-dev
   ```
4. Build the executable

   ```
   mkdir build && cd build
   cmake ..
   make
   sudo make install
   ```

Everything successfully installed and the build was successful too.

5. Launch the program

   ```
   sudo ./bin/Protonect
   ```

---

The output does not display any error but the `Viewer` windows stay black :

```
[Info] [Freenect2Impl] enumerating devices...
[Info] [Freenect2Impl] 8 usb devices connected
[Info] [Freenect2Impl] found valid Kinect v2 @2:5 with serial 501696141942
[Info] [Freenect2Impl] found 1 devices
[Info] [Freenect2DeviceImpl] opening...
[Info] [Freenect2DeviceImpl] opened
[Info] [Freenect2DeviceImpl] starting...
[Debug] [Freenect2DeviceImpl] ReadData0x14 response
[Debug] [Freenect2DeviceImpl] 92 bytes of raw data
0x0000:  00 00 12 00 00 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 43 c1 1f 41    2e2e2e2e2e2e2e2e2e2e2e2e432e2e41
0x0010:  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00    2e2e2e2e2e2e2e2e2e2e2e2e2e2e2e2e
0x0020:  0a 21 33 55 c2 00 17 20 00 08 00 00 10 00 00 00    2e2133552e2e2e202e2e2e2e2e2e2e2e
0x0030:  00 01 00 00 00 10 00 00 00 00 80 00 01 00 00 00    2e2e2e2e2e2e2e2e2e2e802e2e2e2e2e
0x0040:  31 33 00 00 00 04 0f 0d 47 4d 48 38 34 36 2e 31    31332e2e2e2e2e2e474d483834362e31
0x0050:  58 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00                582e2e2e2e2e2e2e2e2e2e2e

[Debug] [Freenect2DeviceImpl] ReadStatus0x090000 response
[Debug] [Freenect2DeviceImpl] 4 bytes of raw data
0x0000:  00 22 00 00                                        2e222e2e

[Debug] [Freenect2DeviceImpl] ReadStatus0x090000 response
[Debug] [Freenect2DeviceImpl] 4 bytes of raw data
0x0000:  00 22 00 00                                        2e222e2e

[Info] [Freenect2DeviceImpl] enabling usb transfer submission...
[Info] [Freenect2DeviceImpl] submitting usb transfers...
[Info] [Freenect2DeviceImpl] started
device serial: 50**************
device firmware: 4.3.3912.0.7
[Info] [TurboJpegRgbPacketProcessor] avg. time: 18.4934ms -> ~54.0734Hz
[Info] [TurboJpegRgbPacketProcessor] avg. time: 19.4946ms -> ~51.2961Hz
...
```

`Viewer` :

[image: kinect viewer]

---

**Additional informations :**

The kinect is connected on a USB 3.0 (required) port and I am using Ubuntu 15.04.

What am I missing here ?

Answer (score 0):

It's best to report this issue on GitHub where we can track your progress.

Protonect uses OpenGL be default. What is your OpenGL version `glxinfo | grep OpenGL`? If the depth processor really running? To see if the depth processor is really running, look for `[XXXDepthRgbPacketProcessor] avg. time` log messages.

As you have installed OpenCL driver, you may also run `./Protonect cl`.

Please follow up the issue on GitHub if you can.